# Reference Parent attributes from child - python3

Tags: python-3.x, parent-child

I have what I thought would be a pretty straightforward task, but it has turned into me questioning everything I know about Classes (which to be fair wasn't much to begin with).

I have a parent class and I want to use the attributes of that instance in calculations to be performed in the child class, which is to be created from the **init** of the parent class. However, I don't seem to be able to reference them from the child class.

I have found some suggestions to **init** the parent class from the child class, however, that just creates an endless loop in my case.

```
class User(object):
   def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.child.append(Child(c=4))

class Child(User)
   def __init__(self, c):
    self.c = c + User.b
    print self.c
```

Comment: A User has an attribute Child. A Child should have the same attributes as a User. So a child should have a Child. And this Child should have a Child, who should have a Child, who should have a Child.... I guess you understood the endless loop. Should the Child only inherits from the User the attributes a and b ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code and the question, I'm guessing Child really just needs to access some attributes of User, in this example `self.b`

Inheritance is not the way to go. Inheritance is when you want to reuse a lot of attributes and methods, and re-implement some of them. Like two class "car" and "truck" would both inherits from a class "vehicles"

What you describe with the "Parent-Child" is more like ownership. The class User owns some Child (as attributes), and you want the Child to access data from their owner. What you need to do is to pass a reference of the owner (parent) to the child.

```
class User(object):
   def __init__(self, b):
    self.b = b
    self.child.append(Child(c=4,parent=self))

class Child(object)
   def __init__(self, c, parent):
    self.parent=parent
    self.c = c + self.parent.b
    print(self.c)
```

Of course in this really simple example, the most obvious way to program it would be to pass `b` in the child constructor, like this:

```
class User(object):
   def __init__(self, b):
    self.b = b
    self.child.append(Child(4,b))

class Child(object)
   def __init__(self, c, b):
    self.c = c + .b
    print(self.c)
```

But for a more complex task, passing a reference to the parent can be better or necessary.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! Just a quick question regarding efficiency: If I want Child to have access to 10 attributes of parent (which has 100), is it better to create a method that would collect those 10 attributes to be passed to the Child, or could I pass the whole Parent class, even if I am only using some of the attributes? I guess I am asking, would passing the whole class slow down Python more?

Comment: You're only passing a reference to the parent class, not a copy, so it won't slow down at all. Copying the 10 attributes would be longer.